# Shaka Player - Get Widevine License URL

Tags: video.js, mpeg-dash, widevine, shaka

I want to play DASH file in Shaka Player with help of Widevine DRM.
And for this, i want to make XHR request to get Widevine License URL and then give that license URL to Shaka Player so it can play my DASH .mpd file and i do not know how to do that, So can anybody help me to solve this ?

For example::

My Dash File - https://example.com/7844-6093f36b051c9/manifest.mpd

URL to get Widevine DRM License URL - https://example/v1/drm/content/ticket/?streamId=47072

Response that I'm getting from above link is as below & In that response I'm getting actual Widevine License URL which i need to apply to Shaka Player..

[image]

And When this, **licence_server_url** (From Above Response, I'm getting this URL) is called from player, I'm getting response like this

[image]

So I have Widevine DRM License URL but I don't know how to use this in such way with Shaka Player so that my Dash .mpd file can star playing..

So can anybody please help to solve this.. ?
It would be really nice and awesome if anybody can solve my issue and help me..

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: The video links you shared don't appear to work anymore

Answer (score 1):

To configure Widevine license servers URL in Shaka Player, the following config is used in the player API:

```js
player.configure({
  drm: {
    servers: {
      'com.widevine.alpha': 'https://foo.bar/drm/widevine',
      'com.microsoft.playready': 'https://foo.bar/drm/playready'
    }
  }
});
```

Morte info here (at the time of writing): https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/tutorial-drm-config.html

In case it is not clear from the Shaka documentation, for WIdevine license requests the request must be made by the player and the widevine client on the device/browser. The license request and response are signed by the widevine license client and the widevine server respectively and cannot be read by any other entity, even the OS on the client (unless the DRM has been compromised). The widevine client will supply the decrypted license to the browser CDM (Content Decryption Module) and it will use it to decrypt and (usually) send the content directly to the display.